# Left-align nvd3 Pie Chart legend

Tags: javascript, css, svg, nvd3.js

So I've had a look through the source code and everything, there are a number of things I've tried but none of them seem to work.

There is a `rightAlign = true` line which I can change, but setting this to false does nothing, and there's no `leftAlign` equivalent.

All I want to do is left-align the legend on the pie chart, but have it so that it's responsive too (stays in the same position when resizing the window or resizing just the svg). I've tried doing it with my own css but can't seem to get it working, anyone managed this before? Who doesn't mind sharing their solution?

Comment: Did anybody come up with a solution? I too was unable to left align the legend. The legend always stayed for about 150-200 px far from the left edge, no matter what I tried.

Comment: I have been trying to resolve the same issue with no success... Was unable to understand at what tags and at what JS or CSS level this indentation happens.